# Fast computation of inverse real valued function

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a function y = f(x) defined as a sum of two trigonometric functions (with different pulsations).
I defined an interval [0,T] for which the function is invertible. I provided the formula below.

```
def initial_function(t):
    return 0.5*(m_plus-m_minus+A_plus*math.cos(w_plus*t+phi_plus)-A_minus*math.cos(w_minus*t+phi_minus))
```

I would like to compute the function x=g(y), inverse of the initial function, and its first derivative and second derivative. 
What is the best way to proceed ?

I need the algorithm to run as fast as possible as I am constantly calling this function when the program is running. Offline computation are possible.

Comment: define a reasonably small increment `i` and precompute all pairs `(f(n*i), n*i)` for `n = 0..ceil(T/i)`, store the result in an array indexed by possible values of `n`. when calling, use `floor(y/i)` as an index into this array.

Comment: Would you mind writing the inverse function of the `initial_function`?  A quick run through both mathematica and maple did not return any useful results.

Comment: Actually, the function is not invertible analytically (I also tried via maple and mathematica) so I do not know the expression of g.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you cannot precompute *all* possible values at which you need to evaluate the function, you can use an interpolator. Your function is invertible, so [`scipy.interpolate.PchipInterpolator`](https://#%20https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.PchipInterpolator.html) is a reasonable choice because it uses monotonic cubic splines.

```py
from scipy import interpolate

# grid on which to evaluate function
t = np.linspace(0, T, 10000)
# (increase the number of function evaluation points to improve accuracy)

# Interpolate the inverse of the function
g = interpolate.PchipInterpolator(f(t), t)

# Test "round trip" - show that `g` is the inverse of `f`)
t2 = (t[1:] + t[:-1])/2
np.testing.assert_allclose(g(f(t2)), t2)  # passes
```

Now the derivatives are easy. We use the `derivative` method to (analytically) take the derivative of the spline, returning callables that can be evaluated just like `f` and `g`.

```py
dg = g.derivative()
ddg = dg.derivative()
```

Now `g` and the derivatives are approximately as fast as the original function.

```py
%timeit f(t2)  # 436 µs ± 9.82 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

y = f(t2)
%timeit g(y)  # 463 µs ± 88.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit dg(y)  # 521 µs ± 139 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit ddg(y)  # 425 µs ± 104 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

---

Note: this answer depends on a pending edit which would define the function and provide example parameters:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Example parameters
m1, A1, w1, phi1 = 1, 2, 4, 3
m2, A2, w2, phi2 = 5, 6, 8, 7

# Function to be inverted
def f(t):
    f1 = A1 * np.cos(w1*t + phi1)
    f2 = A2 * np.cos(w2*t + phi2)
    return (m1 - m2 + f1 - f2) / 2

# Function is invertible on this interval
T = 0.25
interval = [0, T]
t = np.linspace(*interval, 300)
```